# Finite extension of a field $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: field-theory, intuition, extension-field

I have an elliptic curve $E$ defined over a field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime and I need to let $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ be the closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and then choose points $P\in E\left(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}\right)$

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2145408/401264) I was told that this is equivalent to:

> choosing points in finite algebraic extensions of your $\mathbb{F}_p$ 
>   (since the algebraic closure is just the union of these) so what you really
>   want is to construct these finite extensions and work with them

however my question now is how do I go about constructing the finite extension of a field $\mathbb{F}_p$?

I am self-teaching so assume limited knowledge of complex maths and theorems

Answer (score 0):

All finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are of the form
$$
\mathbb{F}_p[\alpha],
$$
where $\alpha$ is a root of a monic, irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of some degree $n$.

Such an extension has order $p^{n}$. Given $p$ and $n$, there is up to isomorphism exactly one such extension.

Calculating in such an extension goes like this. Elements can be uniquely written in the form
$$\tag{elts}
a_{0} + a_{1} \alpha + \dots + a_{n-1} \alpha^{n-1},
$$
for $a_{i} \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Sums are straighforward.

As to products, you work them out and then use the fact that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ to reduce to the form (elts).
In other words, elements (elts) are of the form $g(\alpha)$, where $g(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ has degree less than $n$ (including $g(x) = 0$). To calculate $g(\alpha) h(\alpha)$, you first compute the product $g(x) h(x)$ of the two polynomials, divide by $f(x)$ to get
$$
g(x) h(x) = q(x) f(x) + r(x)
$$
for some $q(x), r(x)$, where $r(x)$ has degree less than $n$ (or $r(x) = 0$), and then $g(\alpha) h(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$ will be in the form (elts).

This is a $\text{crash}^{n}$ course in finite fields. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) has much more, including worked out examples.